# Finding the angles of polar curves when calculating the area

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am trying to understand how to choose the angles when doing area calculations on polar curves.

For example, to find the area inner loop of this limacon, $1+2\sin\theta$, I can identify four angles that seem to be tangent to where the limacon intersects with $0$. They are $\pi\over6$, $5\pi\over6$,  $7\pi\over6$ , and $11\pi\over6$. I am assuming that the integral has to start and stop with these angles, because $0$ is where the inner loop of the limacon starts and stops. How do I know which ones to use to find the area of the inner loop (as opposed to the outer loop)? My book says the area is actually $\int_{7\pi\over6}^{3\pi\over2}(1+2\sin\theta)^2d\theta$, but I don't understand where this comes from, especially the $3\pi\over2$, which doesn't seem to be a starting or stopping point of the inner loop.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the inner loop has an interval $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ which tells that the inner loop is defined by $\sin\theta=-\dfrac12$ which gives us $\theta_{min}=\dfrac{7\pi}{6}$ and $\theta_{max}=\dfrac{11\pi}{6}$.

Therefore, the area of the inner loop is $$\int_{\theta_{min}}^{\theta_{max}}\dfrac12r^2\theta\ d\theta=\int_{\frac{7\pi}{6}}^{\frac{11\pi}{6}}\dfrac12[1+2\sin\theta]^2=\pi-\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: Would you just explain why the inner loop has an interval of $θ∈[0,2π]$?

Comment: @agblt Notice in the above diagram that the inner loop is only in $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ quadrant. So, we need $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer to not only answer my specific question, but to give a general explanation of how finding the area of the limacon works, because in the many resources I looked at, I felt this point was insufficiently explained to me as a beginner.

In regards to my specific question, only two of those points I mentioned are valid choices, they are $7\pi\over6$ and $11\pi\over6$, because they are solutions to a point on the inner loop, $r=0$, as $1+2\sin\theta=0$ is on the inner loop.  The other points, $\pi\over6$ and $5\pi\over6$ are not valid choices because they are not solutions to $1+2\sin\theta$ at any point on the inner loop, (the only time they are solutions are when $1+2\sin\theta=2$, which only happens on the outer loop.)

A better question would have been **(a)** how to determine the starting and ending angles of  the *outer* loop.  A different way of phrasing the question is, **(b)** how do we know that $7\pi\over6$ and $11\pi\over6$ are the starting and ending angles of the inner loop and not the outer loop?

Part of what motivates this question is a different question: **(c)** Why must we indeed have to worry at all about $7\pi\over6$ and $11\pi\over6$ when calculating the outer loop? If the only reason why we chose those angles were because we set $1+2\sin\theta=0$ out of convenience, because $r=0$ is a convenient starting point that is easy to find, but that is the reason for the confusion, then why not choose a different point that is definitely *not* on the inner loop such as $1+2\sin\theta=2$ and start from there to find the outer loop?

The answer to **(c)** is that it is not possible to find only the area of the outer loop with any starting point other than $0$. Observe what happens if we start at angle $\theta ={\pi\over6}$ where $r=2$.
[image]

As you can see, if we start from there, we are forced to traverse the inner loop to get back where we started from! The *only* way to avoid this is to start at $r=0$, where we will not have to traverse the inner loop:

[image]

So it turns out that our strength is also our downfall, because in choosing $0$ to avoid traversing the inner loop, we also fall prey to confusion as $0$ is also a valid starting point for the inner loop, and this leads to the question of how we choose the right angles that are solutions for $r=0$ that will only traverse the outer loop and not the inner loop, hence questions **(a)** and **(b)**.

The answer to these is that for polar curves, we can only go *counter*-clockwise, as the whole angle system goes in a counter-clockwise direction starting for $0$ and going counter-clockwise to $2\pi$, and further if necessary. Therefore, it is impossible to start at $7\pi\over6$ and go to $11\pi\over6$ in a *clockwise* direction to traverse the entire outer loop of the limacon. It also won't work to go from $7\pi\over6$ to $11\pi\over6$ in a counter-clockwise direction and skip the inner loop, because that would not traverse the entire outer loop of the limacon, only the bottom point at $0$. And it definitely won't work to go from $11\pi\over6$ to $7\pi\over6$ in a counter-clockwise direction, because we can't go backwards in numbers.

So our only solution is to find two angles that are solutions for $r=0$, one that starts on the right side, and a second one that is *greater* than it that will be our ending angle on the left side. So we are forced to choose a new angle that is either less than $7\pi\over6$ (yet is still a solution for $r=0$), or one that is greater than ${11\pi\over6}$ (yet is still a solution for $r=0$). Although there are an infinite number of choices, the two obvious choices are either $-{\pi\over6}$ to $7\pi\over6$, or ${11\pi\over6}$ to $19\pi\over6$.